# A lamentable celebration

Tags: riddle

> Although my existence is often source of lamentation, many see it as a celebration.
>   Give me a diminutive suffix, and I will introduce you to my little sister.
>   Although some keep me in a box like a treasure, I probably belong in the gutter.
>   My sister is often seen as quite nasty,
>   but she has it easy, for she does not need to be circumcised like me.

Who am I?

Comment: Should it be "many see it" rather than "many sees it" in the first line, or is that deliberate? Is it deliberate that the first word of the last line isn't capitalized, unlike the other lines' first words?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan the last 2 lines can be seen as 2 different clues, but they still form just one sentence. Hence the lack of capitalization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're a

> Cigar

Source of lamentation

> As in "close but no cigar"?

Celebration

> Cigars are often used in celebration.

Give me a diminutive suffix, and I will introduce you to my little sister.

> Cigarette.

Although some keep me in a box like a treasure, I probably belong in the gutter.

> Kept in a cigar box.

My sister is often seen as quite nasty,

> Cigarettes are indeed nasty.

but she has it easy, for she does not need to be circumcised like me.

> Cigars need to be "cut".

Comment: ^vote with a note: "illo" is another diminutive suffix that also works

Comment: Good one on the "close but no cigar". I was going for the whole health problem thingy, but whatever XD